# Как проверить количество света?

Tags: java, android, камера, android-camera

Я работаю с `Camera2API` и мне нужно отключить возможность делать фото если на улице не достаточно света...

Я вот подумал о том, что когда используется стандартная камера, то там есть возможность установить `auto` режим на вспышку.

Если я правильно понимаю, то камера работает с каким то сенсором который определяет количество света и если его не достаточно то вспышка работает.

Как подключиться к этому сенсору?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге я воспользовался [этой офф статьей](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment.html)

И сделал так

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
  private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  private Sensor mPressure;

  @Override
  public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get an instance of the sensor service, and use that to get an instance of
    // a particular sensor.
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mLight= mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
  }

  @Override
  public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
  }

  @Override
  public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float luminosity = event.values[0];
    // Do something with this sensor data.
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    // Register a listener for the sensor.
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    // Be sure to unregister the sensor when the activity pauses.
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }
}
```